# 3D ads in iOS devices

Tags: ios, mobile, 3d, admob, ads

I am just wondering if we can show ads (coming from Admob, iAds etc) in 3D view rather than 2D ads popping from top or bottom.

I have a 3D racing game which is currently running in iOS devices and am looking to put some ads in 3D world. I am not sure even its possible :p

Any suggestions!

Regards

Comment: Do you want to put the 2D ad banners on surfaces of the 3D views in your app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible with any of the major iOS ad networks. Most networks like AdMob and iAD only offer 2 dimensional creatives for their ads.